# disable an active link in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm developing tab system and only one thing that I couldn't do is disabled active menu but this is the thing specially which I want is after click another links must be enable you can check out my code below:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="myTab">
        <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">1.tab</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2.tab</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3.tab</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="myContent">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium suscipit alias temporibus officiis inventore cum placeat pariatur beatae sapiente, sed rerum iste corrupti maxime corporis atque omnis. Totam, necessitatibus, consectetur.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas consequatur, id soluta dolorum delectus tempora quod atque, nemo, beatae culpa perferendis placeat earum! Recusandae eos, maxime ipsa, vero vitae molestias soluta iste corrupti expedita sit dicta numquam, nihil veritatis ea odit molestiae qui minima! Esse expedita ipsum dolore inventore ex!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="myContent">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque, soluta, pariatur! Ullam at non animi sapiente, quas temporibus, modi esse quae ut incidunt autem. Totam sint autem quibusdam obcaecati dolorum.</div>

        <div class="myContent">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit impedit autem, sunt accusantium ducimus error obcaecati iste. Sapiente, asperiores libero nostrum ratione dolore. Autem inventore, facere nobis molestiae impedit, debitis!</div>
    </div>

<!-- js files-->
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
<!--/ js files-->

</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.myTab{
    width:700px;
    margin:100px auto;
}
.myTab ul {
    background: #15232d;
    height:40px;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:table;

}
.myTab ul:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
    clear:both;
}
.myTab ul li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.myTab ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#fff;
    font:bold 12px tahoma;
    padding:0 20px;
    line-height: 41px;
}
.myTab ul li a:hover{
    background: #193549;

}
.myContent{
    color:#fff;
    background: #193549;
    font:12px/22px sans-serif;
    color:#e6e6e6;
    padding:12px;
    border:2px solid #122634;
    border-top: none;
}
.myContent p {
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.active {
    background:#193549;
}
```

main.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".myContent").hide();
    $(".myContent:first").show();
    $("ul li").click(function(e){
        var index = $(this).index();
        $(".myContent").hide();
        $("ul li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(".myContent:eq("+index+")").show();
    });
});
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achive, specify the problem a bit more

Comment: hi valar,
i have tab system which i created and after had i clicked to link it must be unclickable.

Comment: `.active,.active a{cursor:default;pointer-events: none;}`

Comment: `if($(this).hasClass(''active")) return false;` put this in your click function

Comment: and also @valarmorghulis 

[code]
if($(this).hasClass("active")){
   $(this).children("a").removeAttr("href").css("cursor","default");
  }
[/code]

this code worked

Comment: yeah sure many ways to achieve that i presume..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st : add pointer-events : none; to your active class

```
.active {
    background:#193549;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

2nd: instead of

```
    $(".myContent").hide();
    $(".myContent:first").show();
```

just use trigger click

```
$("ul li:first").trigger('click');
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jxaf9z0s/1/)